# If/then in the future

Tags: future

A song lyrics got me thinking.

> If you leave me I'll miss you much.

I know songs are absolved of following strict grammar thus I'm not criticizing it. My question is as follows: **what tense(s)* are appropriate for expressing 'if/then in the future'**.

---

Follow all the modifications of that sentence which sound at least somewhat OK in my head.

> <the original>

> If you left me I would miss you much.

> If you leave me I would miss you much.

> If you leave me I'm gonna miss you much.

> If you have left me I'd be missing you much.

<sub>* - in the popular meaning, not the linguistic science's totally useless one</sub>

Comment: We often say *I miss you **so much***, but [we don't normally say](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+miss+you+much%2CI+miss+you+so+much&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) *I miss you **much***.

Comment: ...and when it's not contracted, Americans in particular normally "expand" *If you'd have left me...* to *If you **would** have left me...* But [I'm perfectly happy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/if-i-would-have-lost-you-vs-if-i-had-lost-you) to go with *If you **had have** left me...* regardless of what grammarians say about that one.

Comment: *If you leave me I'll miss you so much* is impeccable grammar. We don't use the future tense in the *if* clause, but in the main clause, it's fine.